# Excel VBA - how to use Match with a matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to iterate through the rows of a spreadsheet called `User List`, retrieve a value in that row and compare it to another spreadsheet called `Permissions`. The value is the row number that the program needs to look on `Permissions`. `Permissions` is a matrix that has `x`'s under the columns of the specific permission the row retrieved from `User List` needs. I want to get those values of the columns with `x`'s and put it in a list in an output spreadsheet.

I'm completely lost on how to do this. I gave it a shot, but I am stuck on using `match`. What do I need to match and how do I access the values of column of the cells with `x`'s?

```vb
Sub Test()
     Dim i As Integer
     lRowUser = Sheets("User List").Cells(Sheets("User List").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lRowUser
        Sheets("Output").Cells(i,2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(..
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can they have more than one column with an x?

Comment: Yes, which is also one of my confusions how to work around that

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what the two sheets look like?

Comment: @rxex I edited my post with the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may get you started? I tested it in a mock book and it seems to work. I know that this solution does not use Match, which is what you asked about, but I didn't think that Match would be the right approach to find the solution to your problem.

```
Sub Test()
 
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim perm As String
 
 
 Set userSht = Sheets("User List")
 Set permSht = Sheets("Permission Set List")
 Set outpSht = Sheets("Output")

 lRowUser = userSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 maxColPerm = permSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 outpLine = outpSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      
 For i = 3 To lRowUser
 
    permLine = userSht.Cells(i, 6)
    UserName = userSht.Cells(i, 1)
    'the user's permission code is on the 6th column of the User List, indicating
    'the line in the Permission Set List that corresponds to the user
            
        For j = 5 To maxColPerm
        'permission codes seem to be listed on the first line, starting 
        'on column 5 of the Permission Set List
            
            If permSht.Cells(permLine, j).Value = "x" Then
                perm = permSht.Cells(1, j).Value
                outpSht.Cells(outpLine, 2) = perm
                outpSht.Cells(outpLine, 1).Value = UserName
                outpLine = outpLine + 1
            End If
        
        Next j
    
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: So I've been trying this out, but it seems to just copy over User ID to the output spread sheet on the first column. It doesn't copy over the permission set IDs

Comment: I think I'm having a little trouble understanding how you are storing the permission set ID, how does doing `Selection.Value = perm` set the ID's?

Comment: Does this account for the case that the user has more than one permission set ID? If it does, how do I make sure that it print out a new row for every permission set, even if it means there'll be another row for the same user?

Comment: what this does is print in a sheet called Output a line for each user with all the permissions the user has. So for instance the User "Test Bober" who has an "ARG Underwriter" profile, which seems to have two permissions, will have a line with that user and two cells with those permission codes. The next line will have the user "Bober Test" and no permissions (since none seem to be granted for that code) and so on.

Comment: What do you mean two cells with those permissions codes? Would it be possible to add another row?

Comment: I should've mentioned this earlier, but the way I have my output spreadsheet is, each row has the user id, user name, permission set ID

Comment: The selection.value = perm does not set the ID's. The iteration stores the IDs in a row of an array called perm where each element is defined by perm(j) where (j) is the column of each permission. If the user does not have a permission for that code the element will be blank; otherwise it will store the permission code. The selection.value = perm prints the array in the output sheet.

Comment: This code assumes that the output sheet lists all the users (one per row) and for each user, it prints the permissions the user has. You can adapt this code to suit your layout requirements.

Comment: Oh, so is this design meant to print all permissions in one cell? I apologize I'm having trouble understanding!!

Comment: no, as I said the row has on the first column the name of the user - that is the outpSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = UserName bit. The rest of the row has the permissions in various columns.

Comment: Ahh okay. I want to have a row for every permission set (a row only has 1 permission set, so a user can be repeated in the output sheet with a different permission set). Do you have any advice on how to approach it this way?

Comment: I edited the answer to do what you just asked.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. i appreciate it